# Capturar valor de un input de cada fila de una tabla con Angular 7

Tags: angular7

Me podrian ayudar.  Ando realizando un mantenedor de asignacion de notas de alumnos y necesito obtener el valor de la nota que se le asigna al alumno fila por fila, pero al usar [(ngModel)] todas los inputs se cargan con el mismo valor. Habria alguna manera de lograr obtener el valor de cada input sin que suceda esto?.

Adjunto imagen para tratar de dejarme entender

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui el codigo HTML

```html
<tbody>

   <tr *ngFor="let alumno of arrayMatricula">

      <td scope="col" header="aula" colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">{{alumno.perRepCod.perRepNom +', '+  alumno.perRepCod.perRepApe}}</td>
      <td scope="col" header="aula" colspan="1" style="text-align: center;padding-left: 22px;">
            <div class="col s2" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;width: 46px !important; height: 42px !important;border: solid #717172;">
              <input [(ngModel)]="ModeloNota.notCal" name="notCal" type="text" style="height: 17px;width: 20px;margin-top: 10px;">
            </div>
      </td>

      <td scope="col" header="aula" colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
           <a>  
              <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" (click)="CrearNota(alumno)" style="height: 25px !important;width: 100px;margin-bottom: 9px !important;margin-right: 2px; font-size: 11px;">Agregar nota</a>
           </a>
      </td>

  </tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: Al ser cargado cada input con el *ngFor, no es correcto que uses la misma variable para obtener o asignar valores, te dejaré un ejemplo de como puedes realizarlo

Answer (score 2):

*La forma mas rápida y sencilla como puedes hacerlo es crear en el objeto alumno una variable nueva el cual usaras para llenar el valor que se ingrese en el input correspondiente es decir:*

```html
<tbody>

  <tr *ngFor="let alumno of arrayMatricula">

    <td scope="col" header="aula" colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">{{alumno.perRepCod.perRepNom +', '+ alumno.perRepCod.perRepApe}}</td>
    <td scope="col" header="aula" colspan="1" style="text-align: center;padding-left: 22px;">
      <div class="col s2" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;width: 46px !important; height: 42px !important;border: solid #717172;">
        <input [(ngModel)]="alumno.notCal" name="notCal" type="text" style="height: 17px;width: 20px;margin-top: 10px;">
      </div>
    </td>

    <td scope="col" header="aula" colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
      <a>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" (click)="CrearNota(alumno)" style="height: 25px !important;width: 100px;margin-bottom: 9px !important;margin-right: 2px; font-size: 11px;">Agregar nota</a>
      </a>
    </td>

  </tr>

</tbody>
```

*Como puedes observar en tu **[(ngModel)]** agregué la nueva variable desde tu objeto alumno:*

```html
[(ngModel)]="alumno.notCal"
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo olvide darte las gracias. y ahora lo hago me habías salvado.